# ReactJS recursion perfomance

Tags: reactjs

I have this function which fetches data from free coins api.

```
export async function fetchAllCoinsPromise() {
  const apiCall = await fetch('https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets');
  const jsonResult = await apiCall.json();

  return jsonResult;
}
```

The issue is this public api has daily limit of calls but if you call api repeatedly it will eventually fetch you the data you need so to overcome this issue I wrote recursion like this:

```
const fetchCoins = () => {
    fetchAllCoinsPromise()
      .then(res => {
        setCoinsArray(res.data);
        return res.data;
      })
      .catch(() => {
        fetchCoins();
      });
  };
```

And then I'am calling this function in `useEffect`. I thought this was a good optimisable solution but after some digging I found some discussions on stack overflow where some devs are saying that recursion is the worst case scenario and I am not sure if it is same for my case. Any suggestions on improving code if it's needed please?

Comment: It would be significantly better to just time your calls, otherwise you're winding up the stack once your daily limit is reached, which will crash the page. Do rate limiting right.

Comment: @DaveNewton by timing my calls you mean setting interval?

Comment: i would use settimeout.... to avoid overlapping calls

Comment: @user14587589 Anything that doesn't allow overlapping or infinite recursion; `setTimeout` is your friend. There are probably modules that can do this for you, but if your needs are simple, it's easy enough to set up the next call after a timeout calculated by the API's rate limits (and how they're calculated, e.g., if it's based on an API key, and all users of your app are using that key from the browser, they call count towards the limit).

Comment: @DaveNewton so basically I can just do like this: `if(!coinarray) setTimeout(()=>function call,1000)) am I correct?`